# Получить this при клике

Tags: jquery

Как в данном случае работать с элементом по которому произведен клик?

```js
$(document).on('.amplitude-paused', 'click', function() {
  this.html('New Text');
});

$(document).on('.amplitude-paused', 'click', function() {
  $(this).html('New Text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="amplitude-play-pause amplitude-paused music--top--btn" data-amplitude-playlist="top--playlist">
Text
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

должно быть $(document).on('click','.amplitude-paused', function() {